# singularity shell inside a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, conda, singularity-container

I am trying to run singularity shell inside a script and run multiple commands inside the singularity image including `conda`.
Below is an example of what I was trying to do. Running `my_script.sh` below doesn't work. After the shell commmand, everything else seems to be ran outside of the singularity image.

```
## my_script.sh ##
singularity shell image.sif
source activate test_env
pbsv --version
conda deactivate
```

I know I can put all the commands inside `another_script.sh` then call that script with `singularity exec image.sif another_script.sh` but I'm trying to avoid creating multiple small scripts.

Is it possible to run singularity shell inside a bash script? or Is it possible to to run multiple commands inside singularity while avoiding having to create a script?

Answer (score 0):

`singularity shell` is for getting an interactive shell session, not running scripts. In your example, the subsequent commands are all run after the shell process finishes, not inside the shell.

If you remove the first line, `singularity exec image.sif my_script.sh` will run the script inside the container. The `conda deactivate` is also then unnecessary, as the environment is inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can run multiple commmands without having to create a script.

Instead of using singularity shell, use singularity exec:

```
singularity exec bash -c "source activate test_env && pbsv --version"
```